# Python ProcessPoolExecutor with bounded queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Is there a way to have ProcessPoolExecutor to have a bounded queue to handle incoming requests while all workers are busy?

In the documentation it is not explained what happens if submit() is called and all workers are busy. However, I did some research and it turns out ProcessPoolExecutor has its own internal Queue which apparently is unbounded. In general using unbound queues is not a good practice as the Executor can be used to crash the system (DoS attack). Something like this can easily crash the system if "some_function" takes too much time to run and receives args which have big sizes.

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    for arg in range(10000000000000):
        future = executor.submit(some_function, args)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to limit the size of the internal queue or have it use an external one?

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner approach which avoids tampering with the `ProcessPoolExecutor` internals would consist in using a [BoundedSemaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.BoundedSemaphore) which gets increased every time a task is submitted and gets decreased every time a task is completed.

This has the advantage of blocking the submission instead of raising an error.

You can find a working example in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/noxdafox/4150eff0059ea43f6adbdd66e5d5e87e).

Comment: I will try it. Looks like a legit solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my question ProcessPoolExecutor has its own internal queue which is unbounded. However, ProcessPoolExecutor._queue_count counts the number of active requests (running + pending).

To me is bounded, just simply create a wrapper on top of ProcessPoolExecutor to check the counter and throw some run-time exception if the number exceeds the desired max queue size:

```
    self._max_queue_size = self._max_workers + max_queue_size
```

and then:

```
def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs) -> Future:
    if self._executor._queue_count >= self._max_queue_size:
        raise RuntimeError(
            f"{self.__class__.__name__} has reached its maximum of "
            f"{self._max_queue_size} active (running + queued) requests.")
    return self._executor.submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
```

May not be the best or cleanest solution but it certainly did the job for me.